# Modeling data with continuous and discrete measurements

Tags: bayesian, regression-coefficients, exponential-distribution

I am working on a project involving a dataset which includes variable which represents "time spent", but the data is a combination of two measurement sources: one is discrete and one is continuous. My interpretation of this is that the discrete measurements are coarse-grained approximations of the true values. I believe that this data should form an exponential distribution. What is the correct way to obtain a Bayesian estimate of the parameter which models this distribution?

Intuitively, I imagine that the solution is to incorporate the idea that the integral values have an extra noise parameter, but I am having trouble producing the exact formulation.

Here is a density histogram of the variable:
[image: Density Histogram]